# Positioning elements horizontally on Jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am very new with Jquery mobile and have been struggling to align these elements. My code is as below and I want the two icons to be horizontally in line with the caption "Heading".

```
<h3>Heading</h3>
    
<img src="../resoruces/speech-bubble-with-exclamation-mark-svgrepo-com.svg" height="24" width="24">
<img src="../resoruces/qr-code-svgrepo-com.svg" height="24" width="24">
</div>
```

With the current implementation it keeps stacking vertically.

What I would like to have is something like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Heading                                            XX
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add inside the JQM `header` a wrapper with absolute positioning. Here is an example:

```
   ...
   <h3>Heading</h3>
   <div class="ui-btn-right">
     <img src="../resoruces/speech-bubble-with-exclamation-mark-svgrepo-com.svg" height="24" width="24">
     <img src="../resoruces/qr-code-svgrepo-com.svg" height="24" width="24">
   </div>
 </div>
```